# is it posible to check flash support on browser from code behind - C# asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

how can i check if a web browser was supported flash or not yet from code behind ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.

You will need to check client side and inform the server side somehow (form post, on the query string etc...).